# Google maps class not working

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, nullpointerexception, google-play-services

I have Google maps in my android application , On most of my android devices my google maps is working fine, but on one device it my google maps is not working.
My google maps class is:

```
public class Map extends  Activity {

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    Intent intent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
          double latitude = 0 ;
          double longitude = 0;

        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();


            intent=getIntent();

            String location=intent.getStringExtra("location");


      /*      GPS gps = new GPS(this);
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){ // gps enabled} // return boolean true/false

           latitude=gps.getLatitude(); // returns latitude
           longitude=gps.getLongitude(); // returns longitude
            }
            */

        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String[] arr = location.split(" ", 2); 
            latitude=Double.valueOf(arr[0]);
            longitude=Double.valueOf(arr[1]);



            //    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            // create marker
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));

            // adding marker
            googleMap.addMarker(marker);
            CameraUpdate center=
                    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(latitude,
                                                            longitude));
                CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);

                googleMap.moveCamera(center);
                googleMap.animateCamera(zoom);

            // check if map is created successfully or not

            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

My logcat for this device is:

```
10-24 03:46:02.535: D/ActivityThread(3501): ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{418378f0 token=android.os.BinderProxy@41837140 {soft.b.peopleassist/soft.b.peopleassist.Respond}}
10-24 03:46:02.546: D/ActivityThread(3501): ACT-PAUSE_ACTIVITY handled : 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@41837140
10-24 03:46:02.551: D/ThemeManager(3501): packageName=====soft.b.peopleassist
10-24 03:46:02.551: D/ThemeManager(3501): packageName=soft.b.peopleassist
10-24 03:46:02.551: D/RRR(3501): path=other/bottom/bottom7.png
10-24 03:46:02.553: D/ThemeManager(3501): sIconWidth=64----sIconHeight=64
10-24 03:46:02.555: D/ThemeManagerHH(3501): infoDrawable=72
10-24 03:46:02.589: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(3501): Google Play services is missing.
10-24 03:46:02.590: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(3501): Google Play services is missing.
10-24 03:46:02.593: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(3501): Google Play services is missing.
10-24 03:46:02.596: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(3501): Google Play services is missing.
10-24 03:46:02.598: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(3501): Google Play services is missing.
10-24 03:46:02.603: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(3501): Google Play services is missing.
10-24 03:46:02.605: W/System.err(3501): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 03:46:02.606: W/System.err(3501):     at soft.b.peopleassist.Map.initilizeMap(Map.java:76)
10-24 03:46:02.607: W/System.err(3501):     at soft.b.peopleassist.Map.onCreate(Map.java:30)
10-24 03:46:02.607: W/System.err(3501):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4510)
10-24 03:46:02.608: W/System.err(3501):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
10-24 03:46:02.609: W/System.err(3501):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2048)
10-24 03:46:02.609: W/System.err(3501):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2111)
10-24 03:46:02.610: W/System.err(3501):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
10-24 03:46:02.610: W/System.err(3501):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1251)
10-24 03:46:02.610: W/System.err(3501):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 03:46:02.611: W/System.err(3501):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 03:46:02.612: W/System.err(3501):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4666)
10-24 03:46:02.612: W/System.err(3501):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 03:46:02.613: W/System.err(3501):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-24 03:46:02.614: W/System.err(3501):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
10-24 03:46:02.614: W/System.err(3501):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
10-24 03:46:02.615: W/System.err(3501):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-24 03:46:02.617: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(3501): Google Play services is missing.
10-24 03:46:02.618: D/AndroidRuntime(3501): Shutting down VM
10-24 03:46:02.619: W/dalvikvm(3501): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e61258)
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {soft.b.peopleassist/soft.b.peopleassist.Map}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2602)
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2630)
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2116)
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1251)
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4666)
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501):     at soft.b.peopleassist.Map.initilizeMap(Map.java:76)
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501):     at soft.b.peopleassist.Map.onResume(Map.java:98)
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1159)
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4584)
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2588)
10-24 03:46:02.624: E/AndroidRuntime(3501):     ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear from the logcat that your device doesnt have `google play services` and since to use the map you need `google play services` that is why it crashes.

```
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(3501): Google Play services is missing.
```

According to [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42543), it is a well-known issue that many Gingerbread phones don't ship with Google Play Service, so instead you need to workaround it checking for installation on app startup, and safely tell the users that their devices doesnt support it or prevent these devices from download the apps in the market.

hope this can helped you around, and gave you a clue of what to do.

Comment: check [post no. #2](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42543), he explains what is the problem and how you can workaround it. I have never tried it but it seems reasonable.

Comment: or if you want you after you detect the users device and you check that it doesnt have `google play services` you can instead direct them to page where they can download `google play services` manually. [check this one out](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/09/26/google-play-services-can-now-be-installed-manually-from-the-play-store/)

Answer (score 0):

Before using google maps API , you need to check whether google play services are available on the device.

```
  public static boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(SplashScreenActivity context) {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            //GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, context, 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

If the google play services are not available, you can navigate the user to playstore to install google play services.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+ GoogleApiAvailability.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_PACKAGE)));
```